# Device Drivers to Read and Write on a Virtual memory on linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, virtual-memory

I am working with a SoC Cyclone V board. I want to exchange data between the HPS and FPGA. They share a common RAM, whose address can be seen on Qsys. I would like to Read and write data in this shared Memory, but dont want to use devmem2 every time i do it. I understand that a driver would be much safer. I was thinking of writing a char driver as it is one of the easy drivers to write for the basic read and write operations.

Is there a way to specify the address to be used by the char driver when we build and insert it?
If not, what driver can be written for the this function (to be able to read and write float values on a specific range of virtual address)?

I have found that user io device drivers or block drivers could be good options. But I am new to this area of development and don't know if these are the only options, or are they any more.

I could really use some help in deciding which driver is appropriate, it would be better if it was a char driver where the address can be specified.

Thank you.

Comment: *"I have a specific virtual address range where I want to read and write data."* -- Why? Don't you mean a ***physical*** address range?  *"I could really use some help"* -- Then explain your situation accurately.

Comment: I am working with a SoC Cyclone V board. I want to exchange data between the HPS and FPGA. They share a common RAM, whose address can be seen on Qsys. I would like to Read and write data in this shared Memory, but dont want to use devmem2 every time i do it. I understand that a driver would be much safer.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use `/dev/mem` just as `devmem2` does? Not sure why you want to write a new driver for this. However, if you do, look at the `/dev/mem` driver source for a model (`drivers/char/mem.c` in the kernel source tree; ignore all but the code referenced via `mem_fops` -- there are a bunch of other devices implemented in the same source file). As for specifying the address, your driver can take run-time command line arguments ("module parameters") via `modprobe`.

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is represent the resources as a device in the device tree, either by creating a custom component in Qsys, or by modifying the .dts file produced by sopc2dts before converting it to a .dtb file with the dtc compiler. Then you could use the uio_pdrv_genirq kernel module to represent the resources as a user-space device. the uio_pdrv_genirq module needs to be loaded with a module parameter `of_id` containing the compatible-id of the device in the device tree.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I will try these solutions.